# Rails application only showing Nginx default page

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger, capistrano

I am having problems with my Rails application that will use Nginx and Passenger. I've already deployed the application and have setup the nginx config file as such:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.example.com;
   root /home/johndoe/test_app/current/public;
   passenger_enabled on;
   ...
}
```

I've already set up the name servers of the domain and added the entry on my provider. However, all I'm seeing is the Welcome to Nginx page. I've checked the nginx error log and I just saw this, not sure what it means and why it's searching for that file.

> [error] 8492#0: *7 open() "/opt/nginx/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No
>   such file or directory)

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You're reloaded/restarted nginx, right?  And your server block is being included when nginx reads the configuration files (i.e., the site is enabled with a symlink on Ubuntu systems)?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted nginx multiple times. I'm not sure if the server block is being included for certain though, is there a way I can check?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I have to define it in a separate server block. Worked great. Found the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824328/why-is-nginx-responding-to-any-domain-name

Answer (score 1):

That error means your site doesn't have a `favicon.ico` file for showing a [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon). If you don't want a favicon, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: I don't quite understand why it goes to /opt/nginx/html/favicon.ico. Is it looking for the index page there? I've already set a root location for the server name in the server block. Am i missing something?

Comment: It's probably coming in for a different `server` block, perhaps the default server.

Comment: But I only have 1 server block.

Answer (score 1):

Verify following configuration should be comment out in nginx.conf

> sudo gedit /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf

```
    # location / {
    #     root   html;
    #     index  index.html index.htm;
    # }
```

This fix your problem of "Rails application only showing Nginx default page"